# Can I add an iterator to the reduce function?

Tags: python, iterator, reduce

Suppose I have the following list: `A = [1,2,3,4]`, By using the `reduce` function, to find the product of the elements, I could do

```
prodA = reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, A)
```

However, if I have another list `B=[9,8,7,6]`, is it still possible for me to use the `reduce` function to execute the following action? (from top to the bottom indicate the steps)

```
9
(9+1)* 2
((9+1) *2)+8
(((9+1) *2)+8)*3
((((9+1) *2)+8)*3)+7
(((((9+1) *2)+8)*3)+7)*4
((((((9+1) *2)+8)*3)+7)*4)+6
```

I'm not pretty sure if I could add something like an iterator for the list `B` to the `reduce` function. How I can do that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is something strange about your example: the steps always add 1 term except for the second step which adds 2 terms.  Is that a mistake?  It seems like there should be a step after `9` which is `9+1`?

Comment: @John Zwinck Thanks for the comment! Yeah I just fixed the steps:)

Comment: You fixed the parentheses which I was also wondering about, but you still have this weird situation where the number of terms in each step goes 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ....   Why is there no step with 2 terms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a job for [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). Specifically, we're going to zip the two lists together, and then we'll express our reduction function as a function that takes tuples instead of simple integers.

Zipping our lists together gives us

```
>>> list(zip(A, B))
[(1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7), (4, 6)]
```

And your function, at each step, multiplies by an element of `A` and then adds an element of `B`. So, starting with `1` (which is a sensible default since the first thing we do is multiply, so the `1` will be the identity for that first operation), multiply by the first element of the tuple and add the second.

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x * y[0] + y[1], zip(A, B), 1)
```

And, with your inputs, we get `370`, which is equal to

```
((((9+1)*2)+8)*3+7)*4+6
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! `1` represents the initial value of `x`, right?

Comment: Correct. It's necessary to have an initial value now, since our "accumulator" (`x` argument) is going to be a single value, whereas our element (`y` argument) is a tuple. Since they no longer look the same, we need an explicit initial value.

Comment: Thanks!! That's really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using zip as the input and 1 as the initial value:

```
from functools import reduce

A = [1,2,3,4]
B = [9,8,7,6]

r = reduce(lambda r,ab: r*ab[0]+ab[1],zip(A,B),1)
print(r) # 370
```

Comment: That is a super-confusing use of variable names.  Your `b` is a tuple containing one element from `A` and one from `B`!

Comment: Agreed.  I figured that since Silvio beat me to the punch, nobody would pick up on that.  Fixed now.